# Hostid of Google cloud VM instance after changing machine type

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to upgrade Google cloud VM that I'm using to host a software license (lmhostid).   Will this change the hostid, in which case I will need to get a new license from the vendor?  Anyway to avoid changing hostid during VM upgrade?

I'm new at this so any help is very much appreciated.   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. Please go to

> Menu>Compute engine>click on your VM name>verify your instance ID

After that you may change the machine type as [follows](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance), you will notice that instance ID will not change after upgrade.

Comment: Thank you.   This worked fine - the hostid did not change.